# SharePoint online - show Calendar as modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like a consistent look in my SP Online Sites. Prefer modern, but cannot find a way to show a calendar in the modern style.

[image]

Here is a document library. Looks great.

But here is my calendar.

[image]

This looks crappy. How can I get this site to display the calendar (and the discussion page) in the modern page look.

Thanks!

Bryan

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an iframe in an embed web part for this, it's not perfect but works for me.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="1000px" 
src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx" 
scrolling="no" style="margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -190px;">
</iframe>
```

Yuliya Haradniuk posted it here - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/calendar-web-part-on-modern-pages/td-p/161291

Answer (score 1):

One possible option: Add a site page and add either an event or group calendar to the page.

[image]

Comment: Joel, I was wondering about doing that. I have 4 things I need to have in 6 different areas - Documents, Calendar, Discussion, OneNote. Could I just create a Site Page for each of these and add parts in there? BTW, how the heck did you get GitHub in our list of apps?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I would say adding a Site Page for each of those probably makes sense. The GitHub integration is an Office 365 connector https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/03/25/introducing-office-365-connectors/